# Calculating probability of getting 3 pairs in 13 cards(similar and related to another question I asked before)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Assuming there are 52 cards and dealt with 4 different players. Each of them will receive 13 cards. What are the possibilities of a player receive exactly 3 pairs?

*four-of-a-kind is considered 2 pairs.

This means we have  3 different pairs and 2 same pairs and one different pair.

For 3 different pairs,

${{13}\choose{2}}$ is for two ranks showing on the two pairs.

$ {{10}\choose{7}}$ is with 3 ranks being chosen and 10 ranks left, we choose from there.

$ {{4}\choose{2}}$ is the combination for the pair in the rank.

$ {{4}\choose{1}}$ is the suit for the non-matching cards.

For 2 same pairs and one different pair,

${{13}\choose{2}}$ is for two ranks showing on the two pairs.

$ {{10}\choose{7}}$ is with 2 ranks being chosen and 11 ranks left, we choose from there.

$ {{4}\choose{4}}$ is the combination for the 2 same pairs in the rank.

$ {{4}\choose{2}}$ is the combination for the pair in the rank.

$ {{4}\choose{1}}$ is the suit for the non-matching cards.

$$
P=\frac{\binom{13}{2}\cdot\binom{10}{7}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot {{4}\choose{1}}^7}{\binom{52}{13}}+\frac{\binom{13}{2}\cdot\binom{11}{7}\cdot\binom{4}{4}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{1}^7}{\binom{52}{13}}=1.3707 \times{10}^{-5}
$$

Does this way of calculating probability include both situations or it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way of calculating is correct in the sense that it accounts for all possibilities and it does not double count some possibilities, **but**...
Apart from the typing mistakes which Alex already pointed out, there is also a conceptual error in the proposed solution.

When you have 3 pairs in different ranks, they can be treated as equal, so you have $\binom{13}{3}\cdot\binom{4}{2}^3$ combinations to take these pairs.
When you have 2 pairs in the same rank and 1 in another, the third pair can be distinguished from the first two, so there are more choices than $\binom{13}{2}$. It is easier to count these combinations as $13\cdot 12 \cdot \binom{4}{4}\cdot\binom{4}{2}$. This would give the following probability:

$$
P=\frac{\binom{13}{3}\cdot\binom{10}{7}\cdot\binom{4}{2}^3\cdot {{4}\choose{1}}^7}{\binom{52}{13}}+\frac{13\cdot12\cdot\binom{11}{7}\cdot\binom{4}{4}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{1}^7}{\binom{52}{13}} \approx 0.199
$$

Note also that this is the probability that one fixed player receives 3 pairs. The probability that *at least one* player gets 3 pairs, would be significantly harder to compute, since they cannot be considered independent. (This is how I interpreted the question at first.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your count with the following remarks.

For 3 different pairs instead of “${{13}\choose{2}}$ is for two ranks showing on the two pairs”
should be “${{13}\choose{3}}$ is for three ranks showing on the three pairs”.

For 2 same pairs and one different pair instead of “${{13}\choose{2}}$ is for two ranks showing on the two pairs” should be “$13$ is for the rank showing on the doubled pair and $12$ is for the rank showing on the remaining pair” and instead of “$ {{10}\choose{7}}$” should be $ {{11}\choose{7}}$.